# Flir camera buffer issue

Tags: ros, camera, buffer

I am using Teledyne Flir monocular camera bfs-pge-27s5c-c for my project
when I connect it, it runs for a while, and then after some time it gives me this error:

```
[ERROR][number.number] : [SpinnakerCamera :: grabImage] Failed to retrieve buffer with error : Spinnaker: Failed waiting for EventData on NEW_BUFFER_DATA event [-1011]
```

What could be the possible reasons? How do I solve this issue??